# C# ITextSharp Copy existing PDF to new PDF

Tags: c#, itext

I am working with a series of PDF files. Many of them have fields, which I am able to populate using iTextSharp.

My issue is there is one static PDF that seems to be reporting an odd size, 9.5 X 12. The page size should be 8.5 X 11 and if opened using Acrobat reader, it prints just fine.

To get around this, I want to create a new PDF Document, using the correct page size, then read the static file into the new document, save it and print it.

I have read a number of the posts here on SO and done a number of searches for a solution, all of which seem to skirt my particular issue.

Is there a way to copy the existing PDF to a new document using the correct page size?

Thank you

> **UPDATE**

Taking Bruno's advice, I did double check the crop box and media box. The PDF I am working with has both. The crop box array is

```
[28.008, 38.016, 640.008, 830.016]
```

And the media box array is

```
[0, 0, 668.016, 848.016]
```

I can alter the upper right corner points making the crop box and media box the same Crop box

```
[28.008, 38.016, 612, 792]
```

And media box

```
[0, 0, 612, 792]
```

But doing so shifts the "text" to the right and top too much, leaving an uneven margin.

I found by changing the lower left coordinates, of the crop box, I can shift the text. In fact setting the crop box to 40, 40, 612, 792 works, but then the top and bottom margins are very narrow.

I need the media box to be 0, 0, 612, 792. Not an issue there. But then how do I shrink the crop box and center the text on the page? I must be missing something.

I've followed Bruno's RotatePages method, in his book, and also looked at this answer, [iTextSharp copy document, resize to custom size, and center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573902/itextsharp-copy-document-resize-to-custom-size-and-center)

But whatever I change with the crop box seems to zoom in on it.

Any advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: Load the file into a PdfReader, change the crop boxes to match your wants, and save everything using a PdfStamper.

Comment: Before you do anything, you should explain what you mean when you say *My issue is there is one static PDF that seems to be reporting an odd size, 9.5 X 12. The page size should be 8.5 X 11 and if opened using Acrobat reader, it prints just fine.* Maybe you have a PDF of which the MediaBox is 9.5 x 12 and the CropBox 8.5 X 11. This would explain why Adobe Reader treats it correctly. You confusion could be caused by looking at the MediaBox when in reality you should look at the CropBox. Please clarify.

Comment: Thank you, both, for your comments. Bruno, to address your comment. You are correct. the media box is 9.5 X 12 while the crop box is 8.5 X 12. However, the printer still will not print the page. So how do I go about shrinking the media box down to the proper size?

Comment: Set the media box to the crop box values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Bruno Lowagie and mkl. With your assistance I was able to arrive at this solution.

```
private void ResizeForm ( string path, string fileName )
{
    string src = path + @"\" + fileName + "_pre.pdf";
    string dest = path + @"\" + fileName + ".pdf";

    File.Move ( dest, src );

    using ( PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader ( src ) )
    {
        PdfDictionary pageDict;
        PdfArray cropBox;
        PdfArray mediaBox;

        float letterWidth = PageSize.LETTER.Width;
        float letterHeight = PageSize.LETTER.Height;

        int pageCount = pdf.NumberOfPages;

        for ( int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++ )
        {
            pageDict = pdf.GetPageN ( i );
            cropBox = pageDict.GetAsArray ( PdfName.CROPBOX );
            mediaBox = pageDict.GetAsArray ( PdfName.MEDIABOX );

            cropBox [ 0 ] = new PdfNumber ( 30 );
            cropBox [ 1 ] = new PdfNumber ( 40 );
            cropBox [ 2 ] = new PdfNumber ( letterWidth + 30 );
            cropBox [ 3 ] = new PdfNumber ( letterHeight + 40 );

            mediaBox [ 0 ] = new PdfNumber ( 30 );
            mediaBox [ 1 ] = new PdfNumber ( 40 );
            mediaBox [ 2 ] = new PdfNumber ( letterWidth + 30 );
            mediaBox [ 3 ] = new PdfNumber ( letterHeight + 40 );

            pageDict.Put ( PdfName.CROPBOX, cropBox );
            pageDict.Put ( PdfName.MEDIABOX, mediaBox );
        }

        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper ( pdf, new FileStream ( dest, FileMode.Create ) );
        stamper.Close ( );
    }
}
```

It may be a bit overkill, but it works for my purposes.

Hopefully, this will help someone else.