# Resizing a PDF page

Tags: pdf, itext

Is it possible to resize a page while keeping its upper margin without altering the lower-left corner of the corresponding Media box (*it seems that Acrobat resizes pages in this way*)? Here is an example:
[image]

Comment: Yes, it is possible. E.g. you can trivially increase the right margin (and so the width) of the page without changing the lower left of the media box. (If this isn't what you're after, please improve your question, e.g. share a pdf both before and after Adobe Acrobat resized it as you want it.)

Comment: @mkl Sure. Increasing the right/upper margin is trivial. However, what about the left/lower margin?

Comment: @user876301 How is your question about the left/lower margin different from the question about the right/upper margin? It's the same mechanism, isn't it? Your question is very strange. Please read chapter 5 of the iText 7 jump-start tutorial ([Java version](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-5-manipulating-existing-pdf-document) / [.NET version](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/chapter-5-manipulating-existing-pdf-document)). If you're still using an older version, please upgrade to iText 7.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I added an example...

Comment: That's not impossible, but it requires introducing an extra transformation to the content stream. If there are annotations (e.g. link annotations), you'll have to add a translation to the `/Rect` of those annotations too. I could give you an example on how to do this, but (1.) I don't have the time, and (2.) I don't think it's a good idea: why should the lower-left corner of the page have the coordinate `(0, 0)`? I can't think of valid reason for that requirement. It's perfectly OK for the lower-left corner to have the coordinate `(-30, -200)`.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I see. So it is similar to https://developers.itextpdf.com/de/node/2138